# Python Date / Time Regular Expression

Tags: python

I am pretty new to regular expressions and it's pretty alien to me. I am parsing an XML feed which produces a date time as follows:

```
Wed, 23 July 2014 19:25:52 GMT
```

But I want to split these up so there are as follows:

```
date = 23/07/2014
time = 19/25/52
```

Where would I start? I have looked at a couple of other questions on SO and all of them deviate a bit from what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Why use regex and not e.g. [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should put this as an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe will strptime still work with the "July" in the xml?

Comment: @user3077627 why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @jonrsharpe worth an experiment - thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the date from string and then [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) it using the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.date.strftime) method of [`datetime` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.datetime#datetime.datetime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("Wed, 23 July 2014 19:25:52 GMT", "%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
>>> dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'23/07/2014'
>>> dt.strftime('%H/%M/%S')
'19/25/52'
```

But if you're okay with the ISO format you can call `date` and `time` methods:

```
>>> str(dt.date())
'2014-07-23'
>>> str(dt.time())
'19:25:52'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Annoyingly this is throwing a Value Error: Wed, 23 July 2014 19:25:52 GMT does not match "%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" - do you have any idea why? Is there anywhere I can read more about the percent signs and letters?

Comment: @user3077627 yeah, [here's the link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)